# Controlling screen brightness programmatically on Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, power-management, windows-mobile-6.1

We have an HTC handset running Windows Mobile 6.1. Is there a way to increase/decrease screen brightness for this device programmatically?

The application is being developed in C#, so a .NET wrapper would be preferable, but an unmanaged API would also be acceptable.

Also, how can we turn the screen on/off to save battery while a particular application is running?

Answer (score 2):

You would [use the power management APIs to change the backlight settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455153.aspx).  Also the WinMo 5 SDKs ship with a sample application called Power Manager that demonstrates how to programmatically change the state of the backlight.  It's in C, but is pretty straightforward to port.

Comment: I have found that SetPowerRequirement function does not work with Windows Mobile 6.1, but it works with lower versions :(